# How to Avoid Duplicate Entries in MongoDb Meteor App

Tags: mongodb, meteor

How to avoid duplicate entries in mongoDb in Meteor application.

On the command: `db.products.find({},{"TEMPLATE_NAME": 1},{unique : true})`

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d0a16ce3b01bb759a771"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "B" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d0b46ce3b01bb759a772"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d0c86ce3b01bb759a773"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d0f86ce3b01bb759a774"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "C" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d1026ce3b01bb759a775"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "A" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5555d1086ce3b01bb759a776"), "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "B" }
```

I want to retrieve only the unique template names and show them on HTML page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/)** where your pipeline stages consist of the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) and [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operators respectively. The [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group) operator step groups the input documents by the given key and thus will return distinct documents in the result. The [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project) operator then reshapes each document in the stream, such as by adding new fields or removing existing fields:

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$TEMPLATE_NAME"
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "TEMPLATE_NAME": "$_id"
        }
    }
])
```

Result:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "C"
        }, 
        {
            "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "A"
        }, 
        {
            "TEMPLATE_NAME" : "B"
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

You could then use the **[meteorhacks:aggregate package](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/aggregate)** to implement the aggregation in Meteor:

Add to your app with

```
meteor add meteorhacks:aggregate
```

Then simply use **`.aggregate`** function like below.

```
var products = new Mongo.Collection('products');
var pipeline = [
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$TEMPLATE_NAME"
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 0,
                "TEMPLATE_NAME": "$_id"
            }
        }
    ];
var result = products.aggregate(pipeline);
```

---

-- **UPDATE** --

An alternative that doesn't use aggregation is using **[underscore](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/underscore)**'s methods to return distinct field values from the collection's find method as follows:

```
var distinctTemplateNames = _.uniq(Collection.find({}, {
    sort: {"TEMPLATE_NAME": 1}, fields: {"TEMPLATE_NAME": true}
}).fetch().map(function(x) {
    return x.TEMPLATE_NAME;
}), true)
```

;

This will return an array with distinct product template names `["A", "B", "C"]`

You can check out some tutorials which explain the above approach in detail: **[Get unique values from a collection in Meteor](https://coderwall.com/p/o9np9q/get-unique-values-from-a-collection-in-meteor)** and **[METEOR – DISTINCT MONGODB QUERY](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2015/02/20/meteor-distinct-mongodb-query/).**

Comment: @garima I've updated the answer with the details on how you can implement it in meteor.

Comment: Hmm, using MongoDB's own `distinct()` like in @Vishwas answer seems to be the more elegant way too me. Any reason for not using it?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Meteor doesn't support distinct in MongoDB (yet).

Comment: @chridam Now that's what I call both a good reason and a shame the same time... ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/) of mongodb like :

```
db.collectionName.distinct("TEMPLATE_NAME")
```

This query will return you array of distinct `TEMPLATE_NAME`

Comment: As far as I know, this is not yet supported in Meteor.